# Unable to rewrite two urls to same folder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a strange problem. I have an .htaccess file that will work only if I make these these bottom two conditions/rewrites different folders. I would like both the products.php and specs.php pages to show: www.example.com/products/ followed by their respective slugs for pretty URLs. As it stands now I can only get this to (kinda) work if I have different folder names. Products.php shows a brief description of a number of products in a category (After domain it would show /candy). The specs pages shows only one product (After domain it shows product line and product name candy/sweethearts). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#products.php pages
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} html/products.php 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^html/products\.php$ http://www.example.com/products/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /html/products.php?slug=$1 [L]

#specs.php pages
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} html/specs.php
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prodslug=(.*)$
#RewriteRule ^html/specspage\.php$ http://www.example.com/specs/%1? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^specs/(.*)$ /html/specs.php?prodslug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have to be different otherwise mod_rewrite won't know if one's a product or one's a spec. If the URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/products/asdljfcaijfaewlf
```

Is "`asdljfcaijfaewlf`" a slug of a product? or is it a slug of a spec? or is it neither? No way for mod_rewrite to know because it can't fetch the slug from the database or wherever that information is stored. All it knows is how to match against the request. That's why you need to allow it to match against the `/products/` and `/specs/` folders so it know whether to route them to `products.php` or `specs.php`.

Also, your rule has an inconsistency:

```
RewriteRule ^html/specspage\.php$ http://www.example.com/specs/%1? [R=301,L]
```

needs to be

```
RewriteRule ^html/specs\.php$ http://www.example.com/specs/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I must still be a little confused about how this rewrite works. I thought that it would wait until it received a request for html/products.php and then it would look at the query string. After that it would rewrite. Since each rule block has different page requests I thought it should be able to write to the same folder because each request is being processed separately and are for separate pages. I'm confused! 
I do have an inconsistency but in my actual script it wasn't there. I had simplified my filenames for the example.

Comment: @user2213851 in a URL like `http://www.example.com/products/asdljfcaijfaewlf` there is no query string. This is what the browser will request, and this is what mod_rewrite will use to match against. It will then, based on the match, either *rewrite* it to `/html/products.php` or `/html/specs.php`, and *create* the query string.

Comment: Oh I see!!! I was still looking at it from the perspective of the unclean urls which is of course incorrect! THANK YOU SO MUCH for your help!!!!